# Problem with simple UDP client/server application

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

Ok. So I have a simple client program sending images over UDP to a specified IP address. At the specified IP a server program is listening and should receive the images.

When I try both programs on localhost (i.e. they are both running at 127.0.0.1) it works and the server receives the images. When I try to put the client and the server programs on different PCs in the same network it does not work.

147.232.24.163 is the server IP, 147.232.24.150 is the client IP.

Here is my client program:

```
  // Initialize UDP.    
  struct sockaddr_in server;    
  int n_sent;
  int socketId = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);    
  if (socketId < 0)    
  {    
    cout << "Problem creating socket." << endl;    
  }    
  server.sin_family = AF_INET;    
  server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("147.232.24.163");    
  // Establish the server port number - we must use network byte order!    
  server.sin_port = htons(42001);

  for ( int iter = 0; iter < 60; iter++ )    
  {
      // load image into jpegBuf

      n_sent = sendto(socketId, reinterpret_cast<char*> (&jpegBuf[0]), jpegBuf.size(), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &server, sizeof(server));    
      if (n_sent < 0) {    
        cout << "Problem sending data." << endl;    
      }    
  }

  close(socketId);
```

Here is my server program:

```
int main()
{
    int bufferSize = 1024000;
    int iSockFd = -1;
    int iLength = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr, cliAddr;
    char buff[bufferSize];
    iSockFd=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
    memset(&servAddr, 0, sizeof(servAddr));
    memset(&cliAddr, 0, sizeof(cliAddr));

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("147.232.24.163"); 
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(42001);
    int cliAddrLen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
    int bindRet = bind(iSockFd, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr));
    cout << "Bind returned " << bindRet << endl;

    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        int iRcvdBytes=recvfrom(iSockFd, buff, bufferSize, 0, 
        (struct sockaddr*)&cliAddr, (socklen_t*)&cliAddrLen);

        if (0 == i % 5)
        {
            cout << "Received " << iRcvdBytes << " bytes from the client" << endl;
        }


        i++;
    }
    close(iSockFd);
    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas why it does not work? I don't get any error messages.

Comment: I have simplified the programs so there is only the essential socket related stuff. I know it's a pain to read very long code snippets.

Comment: Make sure any firewalls on the two machines are disabled... lots of firewalls will filter incoming UDP packets.

Comment: @Jeremy Friesner I made sure of that. To be 100% sure I have uninstalled firewalls completely on both PCs.

Comment: Why are you printing the number of bytes received only on every fifth iteration? (Maybe you're just very unlucky - four out of five messages succeed, but every fifth is failing.) Have you stepped through it in a debugger?

Comment: @Ciaran Keating Well, because the images are supposed to be coming very fast (25-30 per second) so I want to be able to  see with my eyes what's happening.

Comment: I see. For debugging your UDP stuff, it might be easier if you send just one image from a test harness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a solution but your code should be checking `iRcvdbytes` for error in the same way as the send code checks the result of `sendto`.

A return of 0 means the socket was closed gracefully (if connection-oriented - that should not apply here), `SOCKET_ERROR` means an error (in WinSock2 at least).

The socket on the send side needs to be created with `IPPROTO_UDP`, not 0.  This could definitely be causing your failure.

Comment: Thanks. I will try on Monday (I won't have a time to go to lab sooner) and let you know if that could be causing the problem.

Comment: recvfrom will return 0 on gracefully close only on connection oriented sockets.

Comment: There is no such thing as a graceful close in UDP. This is a TCP concept.

Comment: Ok. I won't be able to get to the lab to test this today. I will probably test it on Thursday. Please stay tuned to this question and check it later this week :) I must test it in the lab because my client is actually not a normal PC but an Aldebaran NAO robot (basically I am trying to stream images from the robot to the server PC).

Comment: @Richard - when you leave a comment like this, it pops up as a reminder for me to check back in, so just do that when you have any news. Good luck.

Comment: @Steve Townsend In addition to you suggestion I also needed to remove this line from the server: servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("147.232.24.163"); and then it worked. It seems if I specify a particular IP address server should listen to it won't work but if I leave that out it will somehow pick up the correct IP and receive the data.